# JS | HTML Get selected text from one listbox, on button click set that text to second listbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the option from one listbox, and on button click I want to transfer that option to the other listbox. I tried the following:

First is the JS,

Secont HTML

```js
//Selector
function Selector(){
    var e = document.getElementById("modelss");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}
//Onclick transfer
var button1=document.getElementById("push");
function PushToTable(){
  var content = document.getElementById("transfer").text = strUser;
  button1.onclick=PushToTable();
};
```

```html
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  <h2>Selected model</h2>
  <select id="selectedmodelss" size="10" style="width: 200px;">
    <option id="transfer"></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <h2>Models</h2>
  <select id="modelss" onchange="selector(this);" size="10" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="1">something</option>
    <option value="2">1</option>
    <option>txt</option>
    <option>tttt</option>
    <option>ttt</option>
  </select> 
</div>

<button onclick="PushToTable()" id="push">Push</button>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach was good, but however, the were some issues:

- Define `strUser` globally, so it can get accessed by every function
- Assign your `onclick` attribute to your button via HTML. You wanted to do that within `PushToTable()` which never gets called, so the button would never "get" this attribute
- You where missing your button to push the content

PS: not really an issue, but you don't need to pass `this` to `Selector()`

```js
var strUser;
//Selector
function Selector() {
  var e = document.getElementById("modelss");
  strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}
//Onclick transfer
var button1 = document.getElementById("push");

function PushToTable() {
  var content = document.getElementById("transfer").text = strUser;
};
```

```html
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  <h2>Selected model</h2>
  <select id="selectedmodelss" size="10" style="width: 200px;">
    <option id="transfer"></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <h2>Models</h2>
  <select id="modelss" onchange="Selector();" size="10" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="1">something</option>
    <option value="2">1</option>
    <option>txt</option>
    <option>tttt</option>
    <option>ttt</option>
  </select>
  <button id="push" onclick="PushToTable()">Push</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm so stupid, I  didn't saw those issues, thank you very much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: @Amateur24 Don't worry, you're not! Happens to all of us. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. misspelled `selector()` with `Selector()`
2. define global variable `strUser`

```js
var id, strUser;
//Selector
function Selector() {
  var e = document.getElementById("modelss");
  strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}
//Onclick transfer

function PushToTable() {
  var option = '<option id="'+id+'">'+strUser+'</option>';
  $('#selectedmodelss').append(option);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  <h2>Selected model</h2>
  <select id="selectedmodelss" style="width: 200px;" size="5">
  </select>
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <h2>Models</h2>
    <select id="modelss" onchange="Selector(this);" style="width: 200px;" size="5">
    <option value="1">something</option>
    <option value="2">1</option>
    <option>txt</option>
    <option>tttt</option>
    <option>ttt</option>
  </select> 
</div>

<button onclick="PushToTable()" id="push">Push</button>
```